RecycleBin() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'title', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'deleted_by'
I have a recycle bin model in my Django project that works fine with other models since I have overidden the delete function to soft delete any model object by using is_deleted=True in every model.
class RecycleBin(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000, verbose_name="Title", null=False, blank=False,
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    deleted_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "Accounts.User",
        verbose_name="Deleted By",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name="deleted_by",
    )
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(
        "Tenants.Tenant",
        verbose_name="Tenant",
        max_length=1000,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    date_deleted = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Deleted", auto_now_add=True)
    due_deletion_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Due Deletion", default=None, null=True, editable=False)

However, in my Files model, when i try to delete a file, i get an error RecycleBin() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'title', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'deleted_by'.
class AllFilesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

class ActiveFileModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)

class File(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(
        "Folders.Folder", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False
    )
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='tenants',
        storage=storage,
        max_length=1000,
        null=False, blank=False
    )
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is Deleted?")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "Accounts.User",
        verbose_name="Created By",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name="file_created_by",
    )
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "Accounts.User",
        verbose_name="Modified By",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="file_modified_by",
    )
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(
        "Tenants.Tenant",
        verbose_name="Tenant",
        max_length=1000,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Created", auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Modified", auto_now=True)

    objects = ActiveFileModelManager()
    all_objects = AllFilesManager()

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False, user=None):
        bin = RecycleBin.objects.create(
            title=self.name,
            content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self),
            object_id=self.pk,
            deleted_by=self.modified_by,
            tenant=self.tenant,
        )
        if bin:
            self.is_deleted = True
            self.modified_by = user
            self.save()

Here is the delete function from the FileAPIView as well.
class FileAPIView(APIView):
    def delete(self, request, pk=None):
        ids = request.data.get("ids", [])
        if len(ids) == 0:
            try:
                file = get_object_or_404(File, id=pk)
                file.delete()
                return JsonResponse(
                    {
                        "status": status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT,
                        "message": "File moved to the Recycle Bin successfully!",
                    }
                )
            except Exception as e:
                return JsonResponse(
                    {
                        "status": status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                        "message": "An error occurred while deleting the file!",
                        "results": {"error": str(e)},
                    }
                )
        else:
            try:
                for id in ids:
                    file = get_object_or_404(File, id=id)
                    file.delete()
                return JsonResponse(
                    {
                        "status": status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT,
                        "message": "Files moved to the Recycle Bin successfully!",
                    }
                )
            except Exception as e:
                return JsonResponse(
                    {
                        "status": status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                        "message": "An error occurred while deleting the files!",
                        "results": {"error": str(e)},
                    }
                )

I have tried debugging this to no success especially given its an isolated case with only one model.

May I know the syntax for calling the delete method of the File model?

@Antoliny i have added the delete function where i call the delete method.

I don't see any code that could cause problems in my eyes. Can you show me all the errors?

@Antoliny the only error im getting is the one in the title. I have over 10 other models using the same functionality and they all work fine expect this one.

Open the file where your File model is defined and locate the import statements at the top. Ensure that you’re importing the RecycleBin model from the correct module.
